# Can't remove toner cartridge from HP Laserjet

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

I bought a third-party toner cartridge (a "Linkyo") for my HP Laserjet P2050, and now I'm regretting it. The cartridge is stuck and won't come out.

I can pull it out an inch or so, and it's loose, but there is something holding it in on the right hand side (as you face the printer).

Is there a magic trick that will get it out?

Perhaps there is a cover I can remove to get a better look at it?

Edit: pic added. It doesn't show much, though.

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a picture of this? it will be much easier to see what is going on.

Answer (score 3):

I had an hp 2420 and had identical issue removing a genuine toner cartridge. Seems to be stuck on the right side (even though left side moves about 1 "). I was able to forcefully remove it to check for paper jam. But when I tried to put the toner back, it wouldn't go back all the way on the right side .

I found that on the right side, there was a white plastic circular gear lever that 'pops' out to engage the circular gear on the toner cartridge and that doesn't recess when you pull down the toner cartridge door to put in the toner cartridge (or take it out).

I figured there must be some mechanism that tells it to recess when removing and installing a toner cartridge. I traced around and almost gave up before I found out that the left side of the toner cartridge door had a half moon plastic hinged that connected to it when open. I checked the right side of the toner cartridge door and it didn't have that hinge connecting to it. I looked closer and somehow that hinge got 'disconnected' and went back into the printer body. It was easy to grab that hinged and put it back on the right side of the door. This hinge (when pulled) also recesses/disengages the plastic circular gear into the printer body so the toner can side in and out easily.

So in conclusion for a possible solution, make sure the right side hinge is connected to the toner cartridge door. Check the left side of the door to see what I'm talking about.

Hope this might help others as I was close to buying a new printer thinking this one bit the dust (after 8 years of use).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for my HP Laserjet 400 m401n, the toner cartridge was loose but something was absolutely stopping it from being able to come out.  So I made sure I turned off my printer first, then I was able to take it out easily!! I'm sure this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the drive gear on the toner cartridge.  These will get stuck in printers.  Try to close the front cover.  Let the printer initialize and when the printer goes to ready  open the front cover and try to remove again.  Keep trying that until it comes out.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the right side panel (looking at the printer) and manually disengage the white gear cog with needle nose pliers.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the scanner assembly is fully open to release cartridge.

For me the cartridge was stuck in place, something was holding it and I didn't want to forcibly pull on it for fear of breaking the plastic parts.

After fiddling with it, power cycle, rotating the cartridges several times, I figured out that the cover has to be fully open, and then I was able to easily remove it.

Comment: WHY ARE YOU ***YELLING*** ??!!?!

Answer (score 1):

I just spent a half-hour trying to pull my toner tray out of my M180nw. It was missing the blue handle.  Here's how I got it to release... There's a white plastic lever attached to a spring in the front-end where the blue handle is supposed to be (mine missing). Slide it to the left and the tray will slide out.

Answer (score 0):

Pull it into the right direction, will release the toner cartridge.

[image: Pull into the right direction, will release the toner cartridge.]

Comment: Forcing things is always a bad idea.  If it's stuck enough to warrant the question, forcing it may cause damage.

Comment: Yes its a bad idea.